# Draw Text on Canvas at Angle

Tags: java, android, paint, android-canvas

How can i draw text on canvas as shown in below image highlighted in `Green rectangle` .

[image]

I have done following code.... but from this code i can write text in `straight`. can't write text at `angle`.

```
Bitmap bmpLayered = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmpMain.getWidth(), bmpMain
                .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas cv = new Canvas(bmpLayered);

Paint charPaint = new Paint();
        charPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        charPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        charPaint.setTextSize(24);
        charPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        charPaint.setStrokeWidth(3);

cv.drawText("None", 570, 222, charPaint);
```

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
cv.save();
cv.rotate(-45, x, y);
cv.drawText("your text here", x, y, paint);
cv.restore();
```

where cv being reference to your canvas, x & y the point where you want to draw.

Answer (score 1):

After you've drawn the text to the canvas you could rotate the canvas.

```
cv.drawText("None", 570, 222, charPaint);
//rotate the canvas
cv.rotate(45f);
// or around a pivot point
cv.rotate(45f, 100, 100);
```

[Android Developer: Graphics-Canvas Rotate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float%29)